# Computing a Inf-Sup of $\sin(nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, real-numbers

I would like to compute the following expression

$$\inf_{x\in ]0,\pi[}\Big(\sup_{n\in \Bbb Z}|\sin(nx)|\Big).$$

Any Hint or answer is warmly appreciated.

Comment: In what sense is the inner sup taken? Sup over n, you still have a function.

Comment: For irrational $r \in [0, 1]$, you have $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |sin (r \pi )|=1$$ hence you need a rational multiple of $\pi$ to get the infimum. For example, for $x=2 \pi /3$ you get $1/2$. I suppose that the answer is actually $1/2$, but I don't think it's so simple to prove.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\sqrt 3 /2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\inf_{x\in\left]0,\pi\right[}\left(\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\vert\sin(nx)\vert\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
**Proof:**
As has been pointed out by @Crostul, we have $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\vert\sin(nr\pi)\vert=1$ if $r\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.
Therefore, it suffices to consider $x\in]0,\pi[\cap\pi\mathbb{Q}$.

Hence, assume $x=\frac{m}{k}\pi$ with $m,k\in\mathbb{N}$, $m<k$, $m$ and $k$ are relatively prime.

**Case 1**: $k$ is even.
Choose $n:=\frac{k}{2}$. Then, $nx=\frac{m}{2}\pi$. Since $m$ is odd, we have $\vert\sin(nx)\vert=1$.

**Case 2**: $k$ is odd.

Let $k=p_1...p_s$ where all the $p_i$ are prime. Define
$$n_1:=p_1...p_{s-1}$$
and
$$n_2\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }mn_2\equiv\frac{p_s+1}{2}\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p_s).$$
Note that this is possible since $p_s\neq 2$ and is prime. Now, let $n:=n_1n_2$.

Then, $nx=\frac{m}{k}n_1n_2\pi=\frac{mn_2}{p_s}\pi=\left(z+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2p_s}\right)\pi$ for some $z\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus, the distance of $nx$ from a point where $\sin$ has absolute value $1$ is at most $\frac{1}{2p_s}\leq\frac{1}{6}$. This means that $\vert\sin(nx)\vert\geq\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Finally, choosing $x:=\frac{\pi}{3}$, we find
$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left\vert\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)\right\vert=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$